# How do I remove UL on wp_nav_menu?

Tags: menus, functions

I search on this site and found many [answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wp_nav_menu) for this question. Most of them is not working on my theme.

Here is a one solution I [found](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2011/01/15/how-to-remove-the-container-with-the-wp_nav_menu-function/) and it's working according to my need.

```
function wp_nav_menu_no_ul()
{
    $options = array(
        'echo' => false,
        'container' => false,
        'theme_location' => 'primary'
    );

    $menu = wp_nav_menu($options);
    echo preg_replace(array(
        '#^<ul[^>]*>#',
        '#</ul>$#'
    ), '', $menu);

}
```

This code will remove `ul` at beginning and the end of `wp_nav_menu()`. So in my theme I just write

```
<ul class="primary-nav">
<?php  wp_nav_menu_no_ul(); ?>
</ul>
```

But the problem is coming again when I do not add or activate any menu via admin. `http://domain.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php`

Question :

How do I remove the `<div><ul>**</ul></div>` whether the menu is active or not. Let me know

---

Finally I got it worked :) `functions.php`

```
function wp_nav_menu_no_ul()
{
    $options = array(
        'echo' => false,
        'container' => false,
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'fallback_cb'=> 'default_page_menu'
    );

    $menu = wp_nav_menu($options);
    echo preg_replace(array(
        '#^<ul[^>]*>#',
        '#</ul>$#'
    ), '', $menu);

}

function default_page_menu() {
   wp_list_pages('title_li=');
}
```

`header.php`

```
<ul class="primary-nav">
<?php  wp_nav_menu_no_ul(); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the UL when you add it again anyway? You can use the `menu_class` and `menu_id` parameters to set a class and/or id attribute on the UL.

Comment: I want use superfish. `menu_class` and `menu_id` only will working if menu is activated. If the menu doesn't exists `menu_class` and `menu_id` is not as `<ul>` but as `<div>`. thats why too much question about `wp_nav_menu()` you may test it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function wp_nav_menu takes an argument of fallback_cb which is the name of the function to run if the menu doesn't exist.
so change you code to something like this:

```
function wp_nav_menu_no_ul()
{
    $options = array(
        'echo' => false,
        'container' => false,
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'fallback_cb'=> 'fall_back_menu'
    );

    $menu = wp_nav_menu($options);
    echo preg_replace(array(
        '#^<ul[^>]*>#',
        '#</ul>$#'
    ), '', $menu);

}

function fall_back_menu(){
    return;
}
```

you can even remove the container from the menu and do other stuff with some more arguments sent to the [wp_nav_menu function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @בניית אתרים - Thanks for your explanation. But I'm getting blur here. According to the note on `nav-menu-template.php` `fallback_cb - If the menu doesn't exists, a callback function will fire. Defaults to 'wp_page_menu'. Set to false for no fallback` What should I replace to make `wp_nav_menu_no_ul()` working if I set false to the `fallback_cb` ? Because it return blank for now.

Comment: Now understood :) Thanks a lot בניית אתרים. BTW, how do I pronounce your nickname? Mine `ha ha`

Comment: LOL, glad you go it.

Comment: I've wondered the same thing, it's Hebrew i assume, what would be an accurate translation, out of curiousity.. :)

Comment: :) yes it Hebrew and its a nick i picked up a while a go that if properly translated means something like "web design".

Comment: Please see the other answer from Martti about this.  Instead of adding the `<ul>` and then running a find & replace to remove it again, you should simply just not add it in the first place.  Do so using `items_wrap` option

Answer (score 79):

Actually, WordPress supports this by default:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
));
```

The default for `items_wrap` is `<ul id=\"%1$s\" class=\"%2$s\">%3$s</ul>`.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The other answers of doing a programmatic find & replace to remove `<ul>` after it has already been added are just backwards

Comment: `'container' => false` if you want to get rid of the wrapping `<div>` as well.

Comment: It is true configurable in WordPress by default. Thanks!

Comment: best answer, no need for hack

Comment: this is not working for me in wp 5.2

Comment: I choose this as the best answer. (WP 5.7)

Answer (score 8):

The below code should simple do it.

```
<?php 

  $my_menu = array( 
  'menu' => 'main-menu',
  'container' => '',
  'items_wrap' => '%3$s' 
  );

  wp_nav_menu( $my_menu );

?>
```

Reference this link for the wp_nav_menu function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 5):

If you want to print only `<a>` tags, you may go this way:

```
$primaryMenu = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => '',
    'container_class' => false,
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => 'primary-menu',
    'echo'            => false,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);
echo strip_tags( wp_nav_menu( $primaryMenu ), '<a>' );
```

Comment: this work perfect for me, setting only ` 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ` does not has effect in wp 5.2

Answer (score 3):

For me what worked was this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
       'container' => '',
       'items_wrap' => '%3$s' 
) ); ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this answer is not completely for this question but there are so many people who come to know how to remove ul and li tag in WordPress and add another tag in WordPress.

Like before applying my code WordPress gives these types of output in menu

```
<ul class="*****"><li>abc</li></ul>
```

But someone wants to change ul into div and li into a tag then you should use below code

```
            <?php

                $menuParameters = array(
                    'menu' => 'primary_menu',
                    'link_before'     => '<span>',
                    'link_after'      => '</span>',
                    'before'        => '<div class="tp-primary-header mui-top-home">',
                    'after'     => '</div>',
                    'container'       => false,
                    'echo'            => false,
                    'depth'           => 0,
                );

                echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a><span><div>' );
                ?>
```

This gives output in the following format

```
<div class="tp-primary-header mui-top-home"><a href="#"><span>ABC</span></a></div>
<div class="tp-primary-header mui-top-home"><a href="#"><span>def</span></a></div>
<div class="tp-primary-header mui-top-home"><a href="#"><span>XYZ</span></a></div>
```